# How do I match a for loop with vector declaring in it's body?

Tags: c++, clang, clang-tidy, clang-ast-matchers

I hope to match all for-loop with vector declaring in it's body (might extend to while-loop and do-while-loop later):

```cpp
#include <vector>

int main() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    std::vector<int> foo;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

The AST I got from this program is

```
`-FunctionDecl 0x55c1d33c8bc8 <main.cpp:3:1, line:9:1> line:3:5 main 'int ()'
  `-CompoundStmt 0x55c1d3402a48 <col:12, line:9:1>
    |-ForStmt 0x55c1d34029e0 <line:4:3, line:6:3>
    | |-DeclStmt 0x55c1d33c8d40 <line:4:8, col:17>
    | | `-VarDecl 0x55c1d33c8cb8 <col:8, col:16> col:12 used i 'int' cinit
    | |   `-IntegerLiteral 0x55c1d33c8d20 <col:16> 'int' 0
    | |-<<<NULL>>>
    | |-BinaryOperator 0x55c1d33c8db0 <col:19, col:23> 'bool' '<'
    | | |-ImplicitCastExpr 0x55c1d33c8d98 <col:19> 'int' <LValueToRValue>
    | | | `-DeclRefExpr 0x55c1d33c8d58 <col:19> 'int' lvalue Var 0x55c1d33c8cb8 'i' 'int'
    | | `-IntegerLiteral 0x55c1d33c8d78 <col:23> 'int' 10
    | |-UnaryOperator 0x55c1d33c8df0 <col:27, col:28> 'int' postfix '++'
    | | `-DeclRefExpr 0x55c1d33c8dd0 <col:27> 'int' lvalue Var 0x55c1d33c8cb8 'i' 'int'
    | `-CompoundStmt 0x55c1d34029c8 <col:32, line:6:3>
    |   `-DeclStmt 0x55c1d34029b0 <line:5:5, col:25>
    |     `-VarDecl 0x55c1d33cd388 <col:5, col:22> col:22 foo 'std::vector<int>' callinit destroyed
    |       `-CXXConstructExpr 0x55c1d3402988 <col:22> 'std::vector<int>' 'void () noexcept'
    `-ReturnStmt 0x55c1d3402a38 <line:8:3, col:10>
      `-IntegerLiteral 0x55c1d3402a18 <col:10> 'int' 0
```

Now how do I write a matcher (in clang-tidy customized check) to match such pattern?

I read the document for [customizing clang-tidy checks](https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/Contributing.html) and [Matching the Clang AST](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LibASTMatchers.html), but they don't seem to provide enough information on how I should actually combine each APIs.

---

update: with @Scott McPeak's answer, I can match the for loop with clang-query in terminal but I have trouble transplanting this matcher into my clang-tidy check:

```cpp
void LowPerfLoopCheck::registerMatchers(MatchFinder *Finder) {
  Finder->addMatcher(
      forStmt(hasDescendant(varDecl(hasType(hasDeclaration(cxxRecordDecl(
                                        matchesName("^::std::vector$")))))
                                .bind("vector-in-for"))),
      this);
}
```

When building clang-tidy, it says `call of overloaded 'hasType()' is ambiguous`:

```
llvm-project/clang-tools-extra/clang-tidy/misc/LowPerfLoopCheck.cpp: In member function ‘virtual void clang::tidy::misc::LowPerfLoopCheck::registerMatchers(clang::ast_matchers::MatchFinder*)’:
/home/wentao/Desktop/llvm-project/clang-tools-extra/clang-tidy/misc/LowPerfLoopCheck.cpp:19:44: error: call of overloaded ‘hasType(clang::ast_matchers::internal::PolymorphicMatcher<clang::ast_matchers::internal::HasDeclarationMatcher, void(clang::ast_matchers::internal::TypeList<clang::CallExpr, clang::CXXConstructExpr, clang::CXXNewExpr, clang::DeclRefExpr, clang::EnumType, clang::ElaboratedType, clang::InjectedClassNameType, clang::LabelStmt, clang::AddrLabelExpr, clang::MemberExpr, clang::QualType, clang::RecordType, clang::TagType, clang::TemplateSpecializationType, clang::TemplateTypeParmType, clang::TypedefType, clang::UnresolvedUsingType, clang::ObjCIvarRefExpr>), clang::ast_matchers::internal::Matcher<clang::Decl> >)’ is ambiguous
   19 |       forStmt(hasDescendant(varDecl(hasType(hasDeclaration(cxxRecordDecl(
      |                                     ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   20 |                                         matchesName("^::std::vector$")))))
      |                                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Why does the same code works for clang-query but not for clang-tidy checks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find all `for` loops that contain, somewhere, a declaration of
a `std::vector` variable using this AST matcher:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

PATH=$HOME/opt/clang+llvm-16.0.0-x86_64-linux-gnu-ubuntu-18.04/bin:$PATH

# In this query, the comments are ignored because clang-query (not the
# shell) recognizes and discards them.
query='m
  forStmt(                        # Report any "for" statement
    hasDescendant(                # where a descendant
      varDecl(                    # is a variable declaration
        hasType(                  # whose type
          cxxRecordDecl(          # is a struct/class/union (possibly templatized)
            matchesName(          # whose name matches the regex
              "^::std::vector$"   # given here.
            )
          )
        )
      ).bind("vector_var_decl")   # Bind to the declaration AST node.
    )
  )
'

clang-query \
  -c="$query" \
  test.cc -- -w

# EOF
```

This matcher is expressed as a
[`clang-query`](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/code-quality/static-analysis/writing-new/clang-query.html)
shell script for ease of experimentation, but the matcher expression can
be copied directly into a C++ `clang-tidy` checker implementation like
this:

```cpp
void HelloCheck::registerMatchers(MatchFinder *Finder) {
  Finder->addMatcher(
    forStmt(                        // Report any "for" statement
      hasDescendant(                // where a descendant
        varDecl(                    // is a variable declaration
          hasType(                  // whose type
            cxxRecordDecl(          // is a struct/class/union (possibly templatized)
              matchesName(          // whose name matches the regex
                "^::std::vector$"   // given here.
              )
            )
          )
        ).bind("vector_var_decl")   // Bind to the declaration AST node.
      )
    ),
    this
  );
}
```

To create this matcher, I used the list of matchers at
[AST Matcher Reference](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LibASTMatchersReference.html).
It takes some trial and error to find the right combination; I wish the
documentation was better.  One small tip I can give is you can use the
`anything()` matcher as a placeholder that matches anything while
developing the matcher incrementally.

In this case, the first hard part (for me, despite some prior
experience) was realizing I needed to use the `cxxRecordDecl` matcher
before `matchesName` could be used.  Originally, I tried
`hasDeclaration`, but that matches declarations that don't necessarily
have a name, and consequently `matchesName` will just silently fail
(`clang-query` could be a lot more informative in cases like this).  By
using `cxxRecordDecl`, we're guaranteed to be working with a declaration
that has a name to match, so it works.

The second problem, when translating my original `clang-query` matcher
into a C++ `clang-tidy` check, was an error about an ambiguous call to
`hasType`.  The original matcher had:

```
  varDecl(hasType(hasDeclaration(cxxRecordDecl(...))))
```

Evidently, `hasDeclaration` in that spot causes problems in the C++
context (although I don't really understand why), and my solution was to
just remove it:

```
  varDecl(hasType(cxxRecordDecl(...)))
```

To expand to other kinds of loops, the `whileStmt` and `doStmt` matchers
could be substituted for `forStmt`.

Example input:

```
#if 1
  #include <vector>
#else
  // Simplified stand-in for easier AST inspection.
  namespace std {
    template <class T>
    class vector {};
  }
#endif

class SomethingElse {};

int main() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {       // Report.
    std::vector<int> foo;              // Original example.
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {       // Do not report.
    SomethingElse se;                  // Not a std::vector.
  }

  for (;;) {                           // Report.
    {
      std::vector<int> foo;            // Not an immediate child.
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Corresponding output:

```
$ ./cmd.sh

Match #1:

$PWD/test.cc:14:3: note: "root" binds here
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {       // Report.
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
$PWD/test.cc:15:5: note: "vector_var_decl" binds here
    std::vector<int> foo;              // Original example.
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Match #2:

$PWD/test.cc:22:3: note: "root" binds here
  for (;;) {                           // Report.
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
$PWD/test.cc:24:7: note: "vector_var_decl" binds here
      std::vector<int> foo;            // Not an immediate child.
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2 matches.
```

Comment: Hi @Scott, thanks for your answer. The matcher you provided works for clang-query but not for clang-tidy check. Could you take a minute to read the update in the question?

Comment: I see; that's the first time I've seen it not work when copied over to C++.  I don't really understand the error (the AST matchers are implemented in a very complicated way), but with more trial and error I was able to adjust the matcher (removing `hasDeclaration`) so it works in both `clang-query` and in a C++ `clang-tidy` check.  The answer has been edited accordingly.